# Return the values of an object inside of array

Tags: javascript, node.js, ionic-framework, ejs

I am trying to return a value of an objects that are inside of an array.

```js
const bugSchema = new Schema({
title: {
    type: String,
    required: true
},
 comments:[
    {
        user:{
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        content: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        }
    }
]

});
```

I have tried the following function but it does not return anything.

```js
    <% for (bug of bugs) { %>
                        <ion-card>
                            <ion-card-header>
                                <ion-card-title><%= bug.comments.filter(function (value) { value.content }) %></ion-card-title>

                            </ion-card-header>
                            <ion-card-content>

                            </ion-card-content>
                        </ion-card>

                    <% } %>
```

However I can return an array but it returns the entire objects rather than value of each one.

```js
          <% for (bug of bugs) { %>
                        <ion-card>
                            <ion-card-header>
                                <ion-card-title><%= bug.comments %></ion-card-title>

                            </ion-card-header>
                            <ion-card-content>

                            </ion-card-content>
                        </ion-card>

                    <% } %>
```

The screenshot below shows how the object looks like

[image]

What I am expecting to achieve is to create a *ion-card* populated with comment's content.

Comment: can you share sample  bug  object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this shall work:

```
<% for (bug of bugs) { %>
  <% for (comment of bug.comments) { %>
    <ion-card>
      <ion-card-header>
        <ion-card-title>
          <%= comment.user %>
        </ion-card-title>
      </ion-card-header>
      <ion-card-content>
        <%= comment.content %>
      </ion-card-content>
    </ion-card>
  <% } %>
<% } %>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
<% bugs.forEach(function(elem) { %>
    <ion-card>
        <ion-card-header>
            <ion-card-title><%= elem.content %></ion-card-title>

        </ion-card-header>
        <ion-card-content>

        </ion-card-content>
    </ion-card>
<% }) %>
```

This should work, I haven't tested it. Keep in mind that Array.filter returns an array with elements that pass a condition. If you want to iterate all the elements do Array.forEach.

**EDIT**

Working example:

```js
const ejs = require("ejs");

let post = {
    _id: 123,
    title: "Comments",
    description: "...",
    date: "...",
    time: 15.2,
    assignedTo: "Elon Musk",
    status: "open",
    comments: [
        {
            user: "Elon",
            content: "Test1"
        },
        {
            user: "Elon2",
            content: "Test2"
        }
    ]
};

let render = ejs.render(
    "<% bugs.forEach(function(elem) { %><ion-card><ion-card-header><ion-card-title><%= elem.content %></ion-card-title></ion-card-header><ion-card-content></ion-card-content></ion-card><% }) %>",
    { bugs: post.comments }
);

console.log(render);

//render -> <ion-card><ion-card-header><ion-card-title>Test1</ion-card-title></ion-card-header><ion-card-content></ion-card-content></ion-card><ion-card><ion-card-header><ion-card-title>Test2</ion-card-title></ion-card-header><ion-card-content></ion-card-content></ion-card>
```

**bugs** should be **post.comments**.

Comment: Actually it does not. Returns an error "Cannot read property "for Each" of undefined"

Comment: @HalfMartianHalfHuman How are you populating the variable "bugs"? It should be an array of comments.

Comment: I have posted a sample bug object populated with comments and the object schema. You can have a look on that

Comment: @HalfMartianHalfHuman Provided working example. However you name the variable (I named it as "bugs") should point to post.comments / your object.